# Como definir parametros em um relatório do crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Por exemplo: Quero gerar um relatório do funcionário que eu selecionar, e no relatório esta gerando apenas o do funcionário de matricula 1, independente do funcionário selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda está com dúvida sobre isso?

Como está sendo feita sua busca atualmente no banco de dados?